# SQL Select or join two separate subsets of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subset

Say I have a table `Element` in my SQL Server database with, we'll suppose, nothing other than an `Id` column.

I also have tables `Foo` and `Bar`, which each have a many-to-many relationship with `Element`, such as I have some tables `FooElement (FkId INT, FkFoo INT)` and `BarElement (FkId INT, FkBar INT)` tables to handle the relationship. Note that Elements can be either linked to a Foo, a Bar, both or none.

If I want to find which Elements are linked to a Foo, I can easily find them using

```
SELECT id FROM Element RIGHT JOIN FooElement
```

And I can easily do the same for BarElements.

Here is my question: what is the best way to find which Elements are either linked to a `Foo` or a `Bar`? Below is my current solution, but I was wondering if there was a better option, in particular performance-wise, as all three tables, especially `Element` will be extremely packed with data.

```
SELECT id 
    FROM Element e
    LEFT JOIN FooElement fe ON fe.FkId = e.Id
    LEFT JOIN BarElement be ON be.FkId = e.Id
    WHERE NOT (FkFoo IS NULL AND FkBar IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
SELECT e.id 
FROM Element e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM FooElement fe 
              WHERE fe.FkId = e.Id
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM BarElement be 
              WHERE be.FkId = e.Id
             );
```

With indexes on `FooElement(FkId)` and `BarElement(FkId)`, I would expect this to have comparable or better performance than most alternatives.

Comment: How would you expect this to perform relative to a `UNION` of two `INNER JOIN`s?

Comment: @Nick . . . I would expect the performance to be better under most data distributions.  Plus, this doesn't return duplicates and doesn't need to remove them after the fact.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I get about a 10-15% reduction in execution time according to my tests. Thanks for the solution

Comment: I would also like to point out that this can be further optimized by making sure that the first comparison to be done in the query (in the example, it's `FooElement`) is the most likely to occur.